# How to deceleare html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am to display one message with some styling on top of it. 
eg : `'<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello</span>',`

How can I declare it into the javascript variable so I set my text where I need.

I am setting like this. 
`this.header.setHtml("Hello");` This is working fine but I want to put some cls. How to achieve this.

Comment: `setHtml` please share the implementation of this.

Comment: This is in extJS http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.Label.html#method-setHtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want

```
var spanEle = '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello</span>';
this.header.setHtml(spanEle);
```

Comment: Exactly the same way I tried, But what I was missing is I was using "", like this. `this.header.setHtml("spanEle");`

Comment: @David Yeah. Please do not use "". When you use "", script thinks that it is a string and not variable

Comment: Also any hack by which I can put text into right of header

Comment: @David I am not an extJs expert but since there is setHtml there must `.setText("some text")` aswell. May be that helps ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with a few different methods

```js
function appendMessage(text){
  document.getElementById('message').append(text);
}

appendMessage('Hello ');
appendMessage('world');


function appendHtml(html){
  document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += html;
}

appendHtml('<span class="green">Hello </span>');
appendHtml('<span class="red">World </span>');

function setHtml(value){
  document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML =value;
}

setHtml('<span class="green">Hello </span>');
setHtml('<span class="red">World </span>');

//then if you would like you can use prototype to extend Element to add setHtml
Element.prototype.setHtml = function(html){
  this.innerHTML = html;
}

//you can then use it like this
document.getElementById('prototype_example').setHtml('<span class=red>This works too!</span>');
```

```css
#message, .red{
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.green{
  color: rgb(0,188, 50);
}
```

```html
<span id=message></span>
<br />
<span id=output1></span>
<br />
<div id=output2></div>
<br/>
<div id="prototype_example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your header is

```
<h1 id="header"></h1>
```

Then setting the html should be as straightforward as

```
document.getElementById( "header" ).innerHTML = '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello</span>';
```

All you need to do is figure out how to reach that specific element

For example, if header element is

```
<span class="header"></span>
```

then make it

```
document.querySelector( ".header" ).innerHTML = '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello</span>';
```